# Reorder sub-groups by group in a frequency barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, reorderlist

I have the following problem:

My code is like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = fct_infreq(sub-group), fill = group)) + geom_bar()
```

And the result was this:
[image: my example]

I want to plot firstly the red group (in ascendent order) and after the blue group (also in ascendent order), all this in the same plot.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The following is simply providing the limits to the y-axis in the order you want, without bothering with factors.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  y = LETTERS[1:20],
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), 10),
  x = rnorm(20)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_discrete(
    limits = df$y[rev(order(df$group, df$x))]
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i am not able to run, because i have no Y variable, my Y is a frequence of X in data.frame

Comment: So, i am having difficult in deal with this lack of Y

Comment: You can replace the `df$x` with `fct_infreq(data$sub-group)`.